# CodeIgniter in hostgator doesn't work

Tags: deployment, routes, hosting, codeigniter-2

I trying to deploy a CodeIgniter2 project in HostGator. It should be easy right?? I'm changing this in config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';
```

in config/database.php I change this

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'the username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'the password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database name';
```

in index.php

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

when I type http://www.caribeanrenta.com in my browser, I get Error 404 not found form codeigniter.

What's wrong, am I missing something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!!!, it was all about case sensitive, I work in window and the names of all controller and model clases are capitalized, but in linux, which is the server that I'm deploying, doesn't reconized lower case controllers and models, so change everything to lower and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, resolved it by setting the first letter of controller files uppercase. Example: I had controller user.php and renamed it to User.php and it worked.